# Jquery mouseover appended iframe (same domain) element

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

Here is [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/pMBw2/)  of something I would like to do. I want to mouse over element that is inside iframe (same domain) and then change color of the font. Like in example.

But in my version first the iframe is created after I push the button - [my fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/38g2pyxh/1/). In my example `mouseover` wont work and I do not know why. I am not that experienced with JavaScript and can not figure it out on my own. Maybe what I want to do cannot be done or maybe I'm just missing something out.

```
function load_iframe(callback) {
    $('#iframe').append('<iframe class="ajax" scrolling="no" style="height:190px" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/38g2pyxh/"></iframe>')
    $('.ajax').load(function() {
        callback(this);
    });
}

$(document).on('click','#create',function(callback){
    load_iframe(function(){
    iframe = $('iframe.ajax').contents()
    iframe.find('body').prepend('<b>This is a test</b><br><b>Click here</b>');
    })
    return iframe
})

iframe.on('mouseover', 'b', function() {
    $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

**What I have done so far:** [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/38g2pyxh/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this is simple code i hope to help you .... i am edit your  code**

```
var iframe
var a
function load_iframe(callback) {

        $('#iframe').append('<iframe id="1a" class="ajax" scrolling="no" style="height:190px" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/38g2pyxh/"></iframe>')
        $('.ajax').load(function() {
            callback(this);
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click','#create',function(callback){

                load_iframe(function(){
                    iframe = $('iframe.ajax').contents()
                    iframe.find('body').prepend('<b id="bb">This is a test</b><br><b>Click here</b>');
                      a=document.getElementById('1a').contentWindow.document.getElementById('bb')
    alert('pass')
     a.onmouseover=function(){
     a.style.color="red"
    }
       a.onmouseleave=function(){
     a.style.color="black"
    }
                })

            return iframe
    })
```